# Bell button as input

Tags: input, esp8266

I got a simple bell system from elcom. It works with 12V AC.

When I measure the voltage at the switch it is 1V when not pressed.
When I measure the switch sides to the power input of the bell system I get 0V on one side and 16V AC on the other. Now I want to use the switch as input on an Wemos D1 mini.

When I simply wire the switch to gnd and an input it works if the switch is not attached to the bell system.

If it is attached and I also attach the Wemos the bell rings which is a sign that this will not work in combination. At least I did not yet burn my microcontrolller which I get might easily happen :-)

Any ideas how I can have the switch attached to my bell system and to the wemos D1?

I power the D1 from the same 12V AC using a regulator board. The powering of the D1 already works but I can not guarantee the start order.

Comment: AC  or DC? if 0 to 16Vdc then divide by 4 gets 0~4V which is safe  and works on 5V . e.g. 1kOhm series to 330 Ohm to gnd on port. Since 12Vac is floating you need both wires and 0V side is grounded to mini using UTP ( twisted pair) wire.

Comment: or better 3.3k to gnd. and 10k series to bell to limit current. Be sure mini is powered before bell is powered and be ESD aware.

Comment: I am a bit concerned that the bell has another ground level than the D1 as they do not use the same regulator. Would it help to use an optocoupler in this case? I read about this in some other question.

Comment: Is it grounded? or was it measurement error? or leakage?

Comment: I guess the bell system has an AC-DC converter inside and the bell switch is between ground and an input port of the internal controller. The difference between ground and the input port seems to be exactly 1V DC when the switch is open.

Comment: Which ground? Does the supply have a 2 pin plug. In any case 1V depends on the impedance between them. Can you confirm?

Comment: Not sure. What I see is that the 12 V AC goes into the bell system. Then there are 2 wires for the elcom i2 bus. One of these wires also goes to the switch. The other side of the switch goes back into the bell system. Not sure how it is wired inside. I assume that the non bus wire of the switch is ground so it pulls the bus down to gnd when the switch is pressed.

Comment: If only 2 wires go in then there is no ground. It's floating. If you cant determine, I stand by my advice.

Comment: I understood your question wrong I guess. Yes. The power input has only two wires. There is no explicit ground wire from the outside.

Comment: no problem then, measurement error